# Determining Appropriate Class Structures when Deserializing JSON c#

Tags: c#, json

Per subject line, I've got a largish (300,000+ entries) JSON that I would like to deserialize... I'm familiar with JSONtoSharp and other resources that help generate classes...

Given this JSON snippet (second block of code below), JSONtoSharp recommends I use the following structure (see first block of code)

My problem is that I don't know what word3 -> word300,000 are, nor would I want to define a class for each of them :)

So wondering if there is some generic structure, conversion pattern that I can use?

Thanks for your time and help.

```
 public class Definition
    {
        public string definition { get; set; }
        public string partOfSpeech { get; set; }
        public List<string> synonyms { get; set; }
        public List<string> similarTo { get; set; }
        public List<string> typeOf { get; set; }
    }

    public class Word1
    {
        public List<Definition> definitions { get; set; }
        public int letters { get; set; }
    }

    public class Word2
    {
        public List<Definition> definitions { get; set; }
        public int letters { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Word1 word1 { get; set; }
        public Word2 word2 { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 {
    "word1": {
        "definitions": [
          {
            "definition": "being ten more than fifty",
        "partOfSpeech": "adjective",
        "synonyms": [
          "lx",
          "sixty",
          "threescore"
            ],
        "similarTo": [
          "cardinal"
            ]
      },
      {
            "definition": "the cardinal number that is the product of ten and six",
        "partOfSpeech": "noun",
        "synonyms": [
          "lx",
          "sixty"
        ],
        "typeOf": [
          "large integer"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "letters": 2
    },
  "word2": {
        "definitions": [
          {
            "definition": "being eight more than seventy",
        "partOfSpeech": "adjective",
        "synonyms": [
          "lxxviii",
          "seventy-eight"
            ],
        "similarTo": [
          "cardinal"
            ]
      },
      {
            "definition": "the cardinal number that is the sum of seventy and eight",
        "partOfSpeech": "noun",
        "synonyms": [
          "lxxviii",
          "seventy-eight"
        ],
        "typeOf": [
          "large integer"
        ]
      },
      {
            "definition": "a shellac based phonograph record that played at 78 revolutions per minute",
        "partOfSpeech": "noun",
        "synonyms": [
          "seventy-eight"
        ],
        "typeOf": [
          "disc",
          "disk",
          "platter",
          "record",
          "phonograph record",
          "phonograph recording"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "letters": 2
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use a `Dictionary<string, Word>`

Answer (score 1):

You need a different structure to contain the definitions:

```
public class Definitions {
    public List<Definition> definitions { get; set;}
}

public class Definition {
    public string definition { get; set; }
    public string partOfSpeech { get; set; }
    public List<string> synonyms { get; set; }
    public List<string> similarTo { get; set; }
    public List<string> typeOf { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize it like this (if you're using Json.NET)

```
var definitions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String, Definitions>>(json);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That was very helpful, thanks again for your time. I understood on some level that I would need a dictionary <string, object> when deserializing, and the additional list class makes for the forehead slapping moment that makes all the difference! (that's what I get for relying on online converters). :)

Comment: It’s kind of odd that the actual ‘word’ isn’t in the Json response - I’m wondering how you’re going to derive that?

Comment: Ultimately, the classes I went with were:public class WordList
{
    public Dictionary<string, Words> wordList;
}

public class Words
{
    public List<Definition> definitions { get; set; }
    public int Letters { get; set; }
}
public class Definitions
{
    public List<Definition> definitions { get; set; }
}
Then it was surprisingly simple to get Definitions.key as each individual 'word' from the dictionary, and some iterations got me the definitions... Again, thanks so much for the assist. You saved me a world of hurt and sped up my education.